# cant connect Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. Retrieving network status failed (connection timeout - 82.54.125.179:443)

Tags: connection

```
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.500 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
28/08/38 10:45:16 ص.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
28/08/38 10:48:30 ص.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
28/08/38 10:48:30 ص.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
28/08/38 10:50:46 ص.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:50:46 ص.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:50:46 ص.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:50:59 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:50:59 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:50:59 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:50:59 ص.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:55:41 ص.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:55:41 ص.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:55:41 ص.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:55:42 ص.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
28/08/38 10:58:39 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:58:39 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:58:39 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:58:39 ص.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:59:00 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 4BE52F3FA7271DDA2E497E17C9E334AE0B8E28BE at 82.54.125.179:443) 
28/08/38 10:59:00 ص.800 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:00 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:00 ص.800 [WARN]  4 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 38EDA6D79C126F873AC0D74C4970A6781E80E557 at 69.162.169.221:8443) 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:21 ص.100 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host C36B0EDDAA5209D6D86052F74991B9AB4B68CCFE at 194.132.208.190:32082) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host DC5091A560AE02F760792F6B5EC0140B927D5CB5 at 52.53.45.147:8443) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 43ACC9EE7EB2BCECE909377F5C6591E95E1A60BD at 213.127.178.45:8080) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 4146E1DF19573517DA4304D35DBA511DF0B71F18 at 46.22.208.39:443) 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 10:59:23 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:00:36 ص.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:00:36 ص.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:00:36 ص.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:00:36 ص.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:00:57 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 16; recommendation warn; host 4BE52F3FA7271DDA2E497E17C9E334AE0B8E28BE at 82.54.125.179:443) 
28/08/38 11:00:57 ص.800 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:00:57 ص.800 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:00:57 ص.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host 38EDA6D79C126F873AC0D74C4970A6781E80E557 at 69.162.169.221:8443) 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:01:04 ص.100 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host C36B0EDDAA5209D6D86052F74991B9AB4B68CCFE at 194.132.208.190:32082) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host DC5091A560AE02F760792F6B5EC0140B927D5CB5 at 52.53.45.147:8443) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host 43ACC9EE7EB2BCECE909377F5C6591E95E1A60BD at 213.127.178.45:8080) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 21; recommendation warn; host 4146E1DF19573517DA4304D35DBA511DF0B71F18 at 46.22.208.39:443) 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN] 21 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:01:05 ص.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:10:13 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:10:13 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:10:13 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:10:13 ص.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:10:34 ص.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 22; recommendation warn; host 4BE52F3FA7271DDA2E497E17C9E334AE0B8E28BE at 82.54.125.179:443) 
28/08/38 11:10:34 ص.800 [WARN] 21 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:10:34 ص.800 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:10:34 ص.800 [WARN]  6 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host 38EDA6D79C126F873AC0D74C4970A6781E80E557 at 69.162.169.221:8443) 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [WARN] 23 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:10:59 ص.500 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host C36B0EDDAA5209D6D86052F74991B9AB4B68CCFE at 194.132.208.190:32082) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] 24 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 25; recommendation warn; host DC5091A560AE02F760792F6B5EC0140B927D5CB5 at 52.53.45.147:8443) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] 25 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 26; recommendation warn; host 43ACC9EE7EB2BCECE909377F5C6591E95E1A60BD at 213.127.178.45:8080) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] 26 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 27; recommendation warn; host 4146E1DF19573517DA4304D35DBA511DF0B71F18 at 46.22.208.39:443) 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN] 27 connections have failed: 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  20 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
28/08/38 11:11:31 ص.600 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Comment: You literally just dumped an error message into a question. Tell us what you did to get this error...